# Flutter - Infinity container

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, containers, infinity

i am trying to create a multiple choice quiz in flutter.I want the 4 answer options to always be at the bottom of the page, regardless of the size of the question.The problem is that if the question is long enough to "push" the 4answer options at the bottim, is fine, but if the question is small (as you can see in the screenshot), the 4 answer options are "going up", down from the question. So i thought it was a good idea to use an infinity container, but it didn't work. Do you have any ideas what i should do to "lock" the 4 answer options at the bottom of the page? Thank you.
[short text image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nI5oI.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class questionpage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _questionpageState createState() => _questionpageState();
}

class _questionpageState extends State<questionpage> {

  int qnum = 0;
  int score = 0;
  int seconds = 10;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.indigoAccent[700],
        title: SafeArea(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  '$qnum/10        ',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 28,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  '$seconds',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 28,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  'Score: $score',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 28,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 0),
              child: Text(
                'Question $qnum:',
                style: new TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 32.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                  decorationThickness: 3.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Flexible(
//              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 0),
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 0),
                //padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 30, 0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text(
                      'This is a short question:',
                      style: new TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 26.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Container(
          height: 80.0,
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 20, 10, 5),
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(
                'Να αγωνίζονται σε ποδοσφαιρικές ομάδες όποιας χώρας ήθελαν',
                style: new TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 21.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              color: Colors.amberAccent,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 80.0,
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(
                'Να επιλέξουν την υπηκοότητα που προτιμούσαν',
                style: new TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 21.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              color: Colors.amberAccent,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 80.0,
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(
                'Να διακινούνται χωρίς έλεγχο διαβατηρίων στα σύνορα',
                style: new TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 21.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              color: Colors.amberAccent,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 80.0,
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(
                'Να επιλέγουν τη χώρα στην οποία θα πληρώνουν φόρο εισοδήματος',
                style: new TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 21.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              color: Colors.amberAccent,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanded widget can solve your issue.

Add Following line after second Row widget.

```
      Expanded(child: Container()),
```

Following code also clear more idea.

```
    Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Flexible(
//              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 0),
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 0),
                  //padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 30, 0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Text(
                        'This is a short question:',
                        style: new TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 26.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(child: Container()), // added line
          Container(
            height: 80.0,
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 20, 10, 5),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text(
                  'Να αγωνίζονται σε ποδοσφαιρικές ομάδες όποιας χώρας ήθελαν',
                  style: new TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 21.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
```